# Create a string variable and ask for input on the same line?

Tags: c++, variables, input, cin, variable-declaration

I absolutely hate these unnecessary steps in programming where you declare and assign a variable on one line and ask for an input in the next.

To keep it short, I want to create a variable and ask for input all on the same line.

Currently I'm writting code like this:

```
string name = "";
cout << "Please enter your name: ";
cin >> name; //Too many steps for no reason
```

This is somewhat my goal:

```
string name = cin >> name
```

Obviously that line does not work in C++ nor will it work if I close an eye and prey for it to work.

Is there a small trick to do that? I mean its possible to work with for-loops when assigning an array so why not declaration and input assigment on one line?

**I'm aware that the reader will try to jump out of the window. `goto` proved that theory and yes I use it with pride :)**

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `string name; cin >> name;` A character shorter than your hypothetical syntax.

Comment: Write a `getInput` function that encapsulates `string text; std::cin >> text; return text;` so you can write `std::string name = getInput();`.

Comment: Single line, contained within a single statement: `auto name = [](){std::string name; cin >> name; return name;}();` Although, technically there are multiple statements within the statement.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I know that kinda trick exists but that's not the point. See the way I wrote it, the syntax is important

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try writing a template function, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
T read (std::istream & in = std::cin)
{
    T x; in >> x; return x;
}
```

and use it like

```
 auto x = read<int>();
```

If you want to validate user input (and you almost certainly ***do*** want it in real-life code), you can use e.g. `std::optional`:

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<T> read (std::istream & in = std::cin)
{
    T x; in >> x; return in ? x : std::nullopt;
}

template <typename T>
T read_loop (std::istream & in = std::cin)
{
    while (true)
    {
        auto input = read<T>(in);
        if (input) return *input;
        in.clear();
        std::cout << "try again: ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I also don't understand the downvote. I mean, if the question is "How do I turn this task into something I can ask for in a single line" it seems like writing a function should be one of the first things that comes to mind. Edit : Specially if what you want from that task is to obtain a value.

Comment: This answer could be improved by checking if the input succeeded.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good idea, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Never worked with templates before and it looks like even more work than just writing them on multiple lines ;)

Comment: @StellarEquilibrium it's called an abstraction. It encapsulate the hard work you will have to write into reusable components.

Comment: `clear()` is not enough. It clears error flags of stream, but same data are waiting to be read again (possibly interpret in different way), so you've got infinitive loop.

Comment: @StellarEquilibrium You write the template only once. Actiualy you can just cut and paste the code above and then use it for a lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

So what is the problem?
If you have repeating code (any not necessary annoying) you just enclose it in function/method:

```
template<typename T>
auto consoleInput(std::string_view request) -> T
{
    std::cin.sync();
    std::cout << request;
    T x;
    while(! (std::cin >> x)) {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(200, '\n');
        std::cout << "\ntry again: " << request;
    }
    return x;
}

auto name = consoleInput<std::string>("Provide a name");
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/iUWmrMCbCWGjoiGu

Comment: You where a bit faster than me. +1 for validation

Answer (score 2):

> yes I use it with pride :)

You really shouldn't. Learn to write good, easy to read, small function with the simplest control flow in it. Also, [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

---

You can do that by moving the steps to initialize the variable into a function:

```
template<typename T>
auto ask_user(std::string_view message) -> T {
    std::cout << message;
    T value;
    std::cin >> value;
    return value;
}
```

Now you can do your inputs like that:

```
int main() {
    auto name = ask_user<std::string>("What's your name? ");
}
```

Comment: You don't have to maintain your code, if nobody can read it :) (except when its stackoverflow, then I'm def. avoiding it at all cost.)

Never worked with templates before and it looks like even more work than just writing them on multiple lines ;)

Comment: @StellarEquilibrium coding is a social activity. You **will** have to code with many people. Do it the right way now or a big surprise will wait for you.